# Two different errors in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I want to compute something using numpy and numba. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit,double,int64

@jit(locals=dict(i=int64,j=int64,k=int64,l=int64,suma=double))
def omega_comp_arrays(omega,p_kl,eta,theta,K,L,links_by_ratings_array):
    #new_omega = np.zeros(omega.shape)
    for rating,links  in enumerate(links_by_ratings_array):
        for i,j in links:
            suma = 0
            for k in range(K):
                for l in range(L):
                    omega[i,j,k,l] = p_kl[k,l,rating]*theta[i,k]*eta[j,l]
                    suma += omega[i,j,k,l]
            omega[i,j,:,:] /= suma
    return omega

N_nodes=2
N_veins=[1,1]
N_items=2
N_ratings=1
K=2
L=2

##Definim matrius
theta  = np.random.rand(N_nodes,K)
eta = np.random.rand(N_items,L)
p_kl = np.random.rand(K,L,N_ratings)

suma = np.sum(theta,axis =1)
theta /=suma[:,np.newaxis]
suma = np.sum(eta,axis=1)
eta /= suma[:,np.newaxis]
suma = np.sum(p_kl,axis =2)
p_kl /=suma[:,:,np.newaxis]
links_by_ratings_array = [np.array([0,0])]

omega = np.ones((N_nodes,N_items,K,L))
omega = omega_comp_arrays(omega,p_kl,eta,theta,K,L,links_by_ratings_array)
```

The problem occurs when I run the code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_omega.py", line 39, in <module>
    omega = omega_comp_arrays(omega,p_kl,eta,theta,K,L,links_by_ratings_array)
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method ModuleRef.__del__ of <llvmlite.binding.module.ModuleRef object at 0x7f801123d3d0>> ignored
```

But if I activate the nopython mode, another error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_omega.py", line 39, in <module>
    omega = omega_comp_arrays(omega,p_kl,eta,theta,K,L,links_by_ratings_array)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 330, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
numba.errors.TypingError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 454, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 881, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 846, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
TypingError: failed to unpack int64
File "test_omega.py", line 10
[1] During: typing of exhaust iter at test_omega.py (10)

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
failed to unpack int64
File "test_omega.py", line 10
[1] During: typing of exhaust iter at test_omega.py (10)
```

In other words, I can't do a loop of a list of arrays because the error is in the loop of links (for i,j in links). Any suggestion?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a complete example? What are `theta`, `eta`, `p_kl` etc?

Comment: Sorry, they are matrix, I've just edited the code. Fortunately people from the github documentation answered my question: basically numba doesn't support list of arrays in nopython mode. I put tuples instead and other errors appeared (see the answer here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2818)